# How can I handle custom tags in a Java HTMLDocument?

Tags: java, html, jeditorpane

I have a swing client that renders HTML through the use of the `JEditorPane` and  `HTMLDocument` classes.

The problem I have is that I want to be able to define an area of the document as a container for some text that will be retrieved at a later date, and then use  `document.setInnerHTML(element, data);` to swap out the place-holder content with the "real" content.

So, I decided that I would define a tag similar to this:

```
<html>
<body>
some text <mytag id="1>placeholder</mytag> some more text
</body>
</html>
```

The problem occurs when I use `document.getElement(String id)` - it finds mytag as an element, but it thinks it's a leaf element that has no content and so I cannot call .setInner() on it.  Looking at it's parents list of elements, it thinks there are 3 - my tag has just been interpreted as individual components:

mytag (start)
content
mytag (end)

So, I'm guessing that I need to tell the document (or it's parser) about my tag, but that's where I'm falling flat as I'm fairly new to this area.

So, has anyone had any experience with this at all?  I could cheat and use a span tag, but that doesn't feel right as (excluded for brevity) I also need to store an additional attribute against the tag.

Thanks in advance for your time...

Comment: Do you know anything about DTD's? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to override the HTMLDocument to return a reader that recognises the custom tags. See [HTMLDocument#getReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#getReader(int)) for more information. You'll need to return a subclass of [HTMLReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.HTMLReader.html) which understands the custom tag (via the registerTag method).

Comment: sounds good - although the HTMLDocument etc. are all actually from a vendor & so I'm having trouble getting hold of the reader.  I'll let you know how I get on!

Thanks, 
B

Answer (score 0):

perhaps set your detail as an attribute of your tag?

Answer (score 0):

http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html
That shows how to add a  custom tag. You can use this to write your own tags support.